# Django-Python. Определить тип объекта класса регулярным выражением

Tags: python, django

Необходимо сопоставить тип объекта модели во вспомогательном функционале модуля `service`. Простым способом, конесно, было бы

```
result = type(obj) is MyModel
```

но импорт `MyModel` из модуля `models` в `service` невозможен. Приходится искать соответствие в текстовом выводе типа объекта:

```
result = 'MyModel' in str(type(t))
```

но такой способ весьма не надёжен, т.к. искомый текст может встетиться не только, как класс модели.

Пытаюсь реализовать это с помощью регулярного выражения:

```
import re
result = re.match(r'.MyModel$', str(type(t))
```

например, проверить из `"<class '__main__.MyModel'>"`
но

```
result = None
```

**Как можно лаконично это выполнить?**

Comment: Как вариант, прописать в вашей модели метод вроде `string_type()` который будет возвращать заданную вами строку, с ней и сравнивать. Можно написать промежуточный абстракный класс с реализацией этого метода, который наследуется от Model, а все ваше моедли будут уже от него.

Comment: Скорей всего глупость скажу, но может тогда в самой MyModel сделать метод `def i_am_my_model(self): ...` а в service ты будешь проверять есть ли такой метод у объекта `hasattr(obj, "i_am_my_model")` . Никогда такого не делал, и даже не знаю, наверное сть способ *правильней* :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сравнивать типы классы с помощью строк, некорректно. Если нет возможности импортировать модель в service, то нужно просто сделать третий файл, в который вы импортируете вашу модель.

```
from models import MyModel


def is_my_model_instance(some_obj):
    b = isinstance(some_obj, MyModel)  # используйте встроенную функцию 
    return b


#В файле service
from my_file import is_my_model_instance

# ...
b = is_mi_model_instance(some_object)
# ...
```

Comment: Совершенно точно, эта втроенная функция `isinstance(obj, MyModel)` и является технологически правильным решением.